# Como converter o token expires para uma data

Tags: python, flask, jwt

Olá, estou iniciando a  minha caminhada com Python e JWT, estou me autenticando em uma API externa e tenho como retorno o Token e o    "expires_in", porem o valor vem em um formato que preciso converter para data e assim descobrir quando o meu Token vai expirar para poder renovar o mesmo. como posso conver o valor abaixo para uma data valida usando o PYthon.

```
  "expires_in": 1209599
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A chave `expires_in` não é uma *"Registered Claim"*, ou seja, não existe uma padronização e você precisa descobrir com quem gerou este número para saber o que ela significa. Abaixo explico primeiro os valores padronizados de data do JWT e depois crio um exemplo caso este número seja o número de segundos depois de criado até o token expirar.

---

Se você verificar o RFC7519 que formaliza o JWT verá na [Sessão 4.1 "Registered Claims"](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519#section-4.1) que os *claims* `iat` (*issued at*), `exp` (*expiration time*) e `nbf` (*not before*) são dados do tipo `NumericDate`.

Para entender o que é o tipo `NumericDate` basta ver [no fim da sessão 2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519#section-2) do mesmo documento:

> A JSON numeric value representing the number of seconds from
> 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z UTC until the specified UTC date/time.

Tradução livre:

> Um valor JSON numérico representando a quantidade de segundos desde
> 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z UTC até o date/time especificado.

Ou seja, é quantidade de segundos desde [Unix Epoch](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Era_Unix) e pode ser calculado usando o método [`datetime.utcfromtimestamp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp):

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1622950200)
# datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 6, 3, 30)
```

---

Usando a função acima para o valor `1209599` que você usa no seu exemplo vai dar 1970-01-14 23:59:59 UTC.. então valor do seu exemplo não é o padrão normalmente utilizado pelo JWT. Se esse número representa a quantidade de segundos a partir de um determinado momento (nesse caso 13 dias 23h59m59s), você pode usá-lo para criar um [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) e validar o token:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

expires_in = 1209599
initial_datetime = datetime(2021, 6, 6)  # valor apenas para exemplo
expire_datetime = initial_datetime + timedelta(seconds=expires_in)
# datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 19, 23, 59, 59)

# agora bastaria testar se `expire_datetime` já passou
if expire_datetime > datetime.now():
    # Token expirado
```

Lembrando que este exemplo é para entender como fazer isso na mão, mas o padrão JWT já possui o *claim* `iat` para informar o `datetime` que o token foi criado e o *claim* `exp` para dizer qual `datetime` expira o token. Sendo assim você poderia usar alguma [biblioteca já pronta para isso](https://jwt.io/#libraries-io) e que faça essas verificações automaticamente para você.

Comment: Olá Fernando, Muito obrigado pela ajuda,  eu descobri aqui que o valor que eu informei realmente era o tempo em segundos, o que da uns 13 dias, vou usar o código que passou de exemplo para validar se o meu token já expirou ou não.